# Design patterns to manage z-indexes accross app

Tags: html, css

are there any design patterns in regards to how to manage z-indexes across the app? My app is getting big and has lots of layers. I started with z-index 100 but quickly we started added higher numbers and without caution it became a mess that we want to reorganize into one place.

Comment: Are you using a CSS preprocessor? If yes, what about defining variables (e.g. `z-layer-music-player`) in one file ordered by z-index and manually updating it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Here are a few you might want to consider:

### Basic: Using multiples of 10

Simply using multiples of 10 instead of random arbitrary values can make your code cleaner but can still become a mess, especially for larger apps.

```
.menu {
  z-index: 10;
}
.notice {
  z-index: 20;
}
.error {
  z-index: 30;
}
```

### Using global CSS variables

You can specify your z-index values in one place by using global [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```
:root {
  --z-menu: 10;
  --z-notice: 20;
  --z-error: 30;
}
```

### Using a CSS framework

You might also want to consider using a framework like [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

In Tailwind, you use utility classes to help you work within the constraints of a system instead of using arbitrary values. For z-index, you would add a class like z-10 or z-20.

Comment: since im using typescript i ended up using enum

as an example:



```

    export enum ZIndex {
        BACKDROP,
        SAFE_LAYER,
        POPICON,
        OVERLAY,
        MODAL,
        NAVBAR,
        USER_MENU,
        SIDEBAR,
        TOOLTIP,
    }

```


Maybe you can add it to your answer and i can approve it? In the end i based that solution on your response.